# Suggestions for Multiple 24" LED Cinema Displays and MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, display, displayport

I have two Apple 24" LED Cinema Displays and a mid-2010 17" MacBook Pro. I've used one display with the computer for a long time, but recently acquired the second display.

Given that I have these two monitors, what are my realistic options for using both with the same MacBook Pro? What is the current state of multi-monitor support? Moving to a Thunderbolt display is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

I've looked into this in the past, and from what I know, you have a few options:

1. I'd never really recommend it, you *can* get a [usb adaptor](https://www.google.com/search?aq=1&oq=usb%20displa&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=usb%20display%20adapter) that essentially adds another display port to your computer.  Make sure the one you pick is Mac compatible - there are some that exist.
2. [DualHead2Go](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/digital_se/) is an interesting product that emulates a single double-wide monitor to your computer.  There are some catches:

   - There is a maximum resolution the device supports
   - It works best if the monitors are the same dimensions and resolution
   - It's currently ~$230
   - The computer doesn't see the monitors separately, which means that when you configure/use it, it will act accordingly.  If you put the menubar on the external 'monitor,' it will stretch across both; maximized windows will be two monitors wide etc.
3. I can't find anything to back it up at the moment, but at one point I do believe I saw an ExpressPort/34 video card or a breakout box for a PCI card.  The only thing I can find now is [XGP](http://www.amd.com/us/products/technologies/ati-xgp/Pages/ati-xgp.aspx), but I'm near certain I saw a Mac-specific solution at one point.

Each has its benefits and drawbacks.  If you're not on a tight budget and your monitors will work for it, I'd recommend the DualHead2Go.

Comment: There's a Magma ExpressBox PCIe breakout box and ExpressPort solution available, but I was not familiar with AMD's solution.

Comment: ewwhite, you should consider adding your comment as a solution.